# How to use namespace in Laravel in controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a custom class in `App/Helpers/regexValidation.php`:

```
<?

namespace App\Helpers;

class RegexValidation
{

    public static function isCVC($str)
    {
        $re = '/^[0-9]{3,4}$/s';

        preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

        return $matches;
    }
}
```

I try to use it in controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\RegexValidation;

public function detectfile(Request $request)
{
   $cvc = RegexValidation::isCVC(555);
}
```

When I call this method from route Laravel I get:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
```

If comment this line `$cvc = RegexValidation::isCVC(555);` it works.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having a PSR4 Error,

> I have a custom class in App/Helpers/regexValidation.php

Rename that file to PascalCase as **RegexValidation.php**

after renaming run

`composer dumpautoload`

And it should work.